# homeomorphism between an open sphere and $\mathbb {R}^{n}$

Tags: equivalent-metrics

Thinking about the fact that $f:\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=\tan(x)$ for all x in $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ is a homeomorphism between $\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ gives me a bijective function $j:B \left(O,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} $ provided that $O$ is the origin of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $j(x)=\dfrac{\tan(|x|)}{|x|}x$ for x $\in B \left(O,\dfrac{pi}{2} \right)$ if it is not the origin, $j(0)=0$.

But I have question about its **continuity**. Since I wanted to prove continuity of this function with the definition of continuous function, I wanted to use triangular inequality. But it fails to prove that j is homeomorphism between two metric spaces with usual metric in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it really continuous function? If it is true, how can I prove continuity of this function and the inverse function $j^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \left( 0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$ ?

Comment: What exactly is $B(0,1)$? Your notations are confusing.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to eliminate it :) I want homeomorphism between B(0,pi/2) and R^(n). I'll edit my question.

Comment: B(0,pi/2) means that {x $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ : |x|<pi/2} where |.| is standard norm of a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler example of a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $B(0,\pi/2)$ is $f(x)=(\pi/2 ) \frac x {1+|x|}$. Its inverse is $g(x)=\frac x {\pi /2 -|x|}$.

Your function is clearly continuous at $x \neq 0$.   For continuity at the origin use the fact that $\tan |x| \to 0$  and $|\frac x {|x|}|=1$. [You have to define $j(0)$ to be $0$]. The inverse function is $j^{-1}(x)=\frac {\arctan |x|} {|x|} x$ which is also continuous by  a similar argument.

Comment: @Mvaldi You forgot to define $j(0)$. Define $j(0)$ to be $0$.

Comment: Ah, yes... norm of 0 is 0, so in order to avoid zero division, I must define j(0) as 0

Comment: I'm sorry, but if my knowledge is not wrong, tan(a)>=a for a $\in(0,pi÷2)$. Could you check,please?

Comment: @Mvaldi Yes, I made a silly mistake. I have edited my answer.